# IIS web.config error on new application

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

Strange one. I have IIS on a test server that I publish test versions of web applications.  It has a 'base' site with 10-15 virtual applications.

I created a new application 'Cinema' and published the files there.  When I try to run it I get a complilation error CS0234 namespace 'Mvc' does not exist in d:\inetpub\Web.config. That is the config file at the base site, not the new application which is at d:\inetpub\cinema which has it's own web.config and does not use Mvc.

Most all of the other applications do not use Mvc either and do not get any errors.  Can you shed some light or tell me what to look for?

Comment: I gave up and gave in and installed nuget package for web.optimization which installed the libraries the error was complaining about even though I don't use any of it.  I'll have to assume that IIS applications have a dependency somehow on its parent.

Comment: Applications under a site will inherit configuration from the site. That's well known and by design, so you should get used to it.